# Scriptaculous Effect.toggle not appearing when display none set externally

Tags: css, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I have a problem getting an element to appear using scriptaculous Effect.toggle, I want the element to start hidden and appear onclick. If I set the element display to none inline the element will appear onclick, but if I set the element display to none in an external css file it does not work.

The script is required for a responsive menu so the display must be set in an external css file and the effect must toggle.

Jsfiddle with both examples: http://jsfiddle.net/TjFKy/

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/faq/), you have to set `display: none;` inline on these containers for these effects to work correctly.

Comment: That may be tough. This is a common requirement. You could always set or *reset* `display: none;` with JavaScript. Although you'd be duplicating code (CSS + JS).